# sharing node-redis connections nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis

Working with nodejs and node-redis.

I have a single entry "server.ts" file which bootstraps connections, such as mongoose.

Mongoose, then automagically shares the connection to mongodb so later in the app i can just tap into this connection and query the db.

With node-redis, this doesn't look to be happening at all. Instead the connection is called into a local variable and then left to the developer to handle.

Is there a best practice here, or just stick it into the global namespace?

```
global.REDIS_CONNECTION = new redis.createClient(options)
```

Answer (score 2):

A better pattern is to create a singleton:

```
export class RedisService {
  private static instance: RedisService | null = null;

  private connection!: RedisConnection;

  private constructor() {}

  public static async getConnection(): Promise<RedisService> {
    if (RedisService.instance == null) {
      await RedisService.initInstance();
    }
    return RedisService.instance;
  }

  private static async initInstance(): Promise<void> {
    RedisService.instance = new RedisService();
    RedisService.instance.connection = new redis.createClient(options);
    // Check connection
    await RedisService.instance.connection.check();
  }

  // ...

  public async getItem(): Promise<any> {
    this.connection.getItem(/* ... */);
  }

  public async setItem(): Promise<any> {
    this.connection.setItem(/* ... */);
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
redisService = await RedisService.getInstance();
redisService.getItem(/*...*/);
```

The `RedisService` encapsulates the logic to retrieve/set information on redis and abstracts the use of the redis library.

This is also a step toward dependency injection if you start using Nestjs or Awilix in the future.